# Prevent the linker from locating sections to a particular memory area, TASKING ARM tool chain

Tags: linker, arm, embedded, memory-mapping

On an embedded target(ARM CORTEX M3), I would like to reserve a certain memory area to be loaded by another binary, and prevent the linker from allocating any symbol in the current binary to this particular area. I am successful in locating all default code/const sections to a desired memory area, but the linker places some symbols belonging to sections like `.text.veneer.long*` to the area I want to reserve. How can this be prevented?

What I have tried already is to allocate all `.text.veneer.*` also to the desired area, but what i want to achieve is to prevent anything being allocated to the reserved area. I also tried using `type = reserved rom` definition for the memory area in the linker script, but it's still being used by the linker.

Under memory definition I have done the following:

```
memory FLASH_RESERVED
{
    mau = 8;
    type = reserved rom;
    size = 16k;
    map ( size = 16k, dest_offset = 0x80000000, dest = bus:local_bus );
}
```

And under groups definition this is done:

```
group CODE_DEFAULT(ordered, contiguous, fill, align=4)
{
   select "[.]text";
   select "[.]text.veneer.*";
}
```

The linker however puts `.text.veneer.*` in `FLASH_RESERVED`.

I use Tasking compiler/linker toolchain for ARM and use a .lsl Linker script file.

Comment: what does your linker script look like and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @old_timer Edited the question.